# Logging in is required for Stack Exchange even though I am logged in to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, login

For some rather odd and unknown reason (to me), both the https://stackexchange.com/ and https://meta.stackexchange.com/ parts of the network require me to login even though I am signed in on the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) area, and that was never the case before.

Can someone help shed some light on this for me please?

I remember being logged in not too long ago, since I was looking at a post about something; what it was exactly escapes me though.

**Note:** I am logged in to Stack Overflow on two different web browsers; Firefox and Opera. I distinctively remember being logged in to Stack Exchange on both.

Do both different areas store different cookies (if that's how the system works) and/or have different date/time storage, if I didn't visit both those areas of Stack Exchange that would have caused this?

I did not delete any cookies from either, and I am a [joined member of Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/231583/fred-ii).

I believe that if those cookies were deleted or have been deleted somehow, that I (probably) would no longer be logged in to Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow META.

---

Edit:

I'm curious to know why it's been downvoted. I feel it is a valid question and have not gotten any support for it, nor have I found anything here or on Google. If anyone can clarify this for me in any way, that'd be a good thing, rather than downvoting and not saying about it. At the very least, post a comment/duplicate.

Comment: Are you blocking third-party cookies? See [Global auth is dead! Long live universal login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login)

Comment: @Stijn No I'm not. This is the same behaviour on two different web browsers that I am logged in to Stack (Firefox/Opera). I distinctively remember being logged in on both networks and on both browsers. I am still currently logged in to Stack on both browsers. This is something that started about a day or so ago, so I for one am completely baffled about it.

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 I am joined to it https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/231583/fred-ii