# Logged out of other sites on the network, but not Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, bug, login

As of yesterday or the day before, I cannot log into other sites on the Stack Exchange network even though I am a member there and have posts there.

I am logged in here, but I see the "Join this community" button on all the other sites, regardless of whether I have an account. I did delete my cookies recently; could that be the issue? I checked this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359761/logging-in-is-required-for-stack-exchange-even-though-i-am-logged-in-to-stack-ov), but I don't have third-party cookies disabled, so that's not the issue.

When I go to log out, it gives me the option to log out of a bunch of sites I'm not even a member of and none of the ones I actually am. For example, on the logout list [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) is there, where I do not have an account, but [puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) is not.

I logged out of all those sites and logged back into Stack Exchange, but I still have the same issue as before.

Update: I tried logging in on another computer and it works there, but not on my main computer I use all the time. I use Chrome on both computers.

Comment: What actually happens when you try to login to the other sites?

Comment: nothing, I click the 'join this community' button, click the button to sign in with gmail, and I get redirected back to the same page with the same 'join this community' button, not logged in.

Comment: The problem seems to have solved itself today, about a month after I asked this question, and I have no idea why or how. Should I vote to close this question or leave it, in case someone else has this problem in the future?